How volatile keyword works incase of PG_TRY and PG_CATCH?
Here is the below code which i have tried.
Datum sample_func(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
  int32 var;
  PG_TRY();
  {
    var = 5;
    elog(ERROR, "testing");
  }
  PG_CATCH();
  {
    elog(INFO, "var : %d", var);
  }
  PG_END_TRY();

  PG_RETURN_CSTRING("Function works....");
}

The output of the code is
INFO:  var : 0
  sample_func   
----------------
 Function Works....
(1 row)


When the variable var is declared with volatile keyword, the value assigned in try block is retained in catch block. i.e the output is
INFO:  var : 5
  sample_func   
----------------
 Function Works....
(1 row)

Besides, if the variable var is initialised before try-block, then the value is retained in catch block even if the variable is not declared with volatile keyword.
Datum sample_func(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
  int32 var;

  var = 5;
  PG_TRY();
  { 
    elog(ERROR, "testing");
  }
  PG_CATCH();
  {
    elog(INFO, "var : %d", var);
  }
  PG_END_TRY();

  PG_RETURN_CSTRING("Function works....");
}

The output is
INFO:  var : 5
  sample_func   
----------------
 Function Works....
(1 row)

It is unclear about how the value is retained with and without the volatile keyword w.r.t PG_try and PG_CATCH.

We'd have to dissect those ugly macros to tell. Is this lib open source? One of the main benefits of C over C++ is otherwise that C doesn't have exception handling. Then apparently someone came up with the "brilliant" idea to implement it anyway...

It used jumps so it does not see the path to that code and it does not read the memory. You need to use volatile

@Lundin - it's PostgreSQL - 100% Open Source - I think that they should go AGPL or some sort of "cloud protection" licence, but they appear wedded to the current MIT style one.
